# datatable total amount of all pages dont work, just work the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

please help me with this problem. I want to get the total amount of all pages from my datatable but it dont work at all.

The documentation say that,
api.column( 3 ).data(); // I can get all data like this
api.column( 3, {page: "current"} ).data(); // I can get just the current page

But I am putting in this way (api.column( 3 ).data()) and dont work to get all data from all pages, It is as I am putting api.column( 3, {page: "current"} ).data(); only;

Here the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 //datatables
 table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('Locacao/ajax_list')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "pageLength": 10,

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable

    },
    ],              

    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };         


        // Update footer            

       // Total over all pages
        valor = api
            .column( 3 ) //here should work but nothing
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(valor);
    }

   });
```

Thanks advance!!!

Comment: You forgot to use a language tag....

Comment: sorry, I put :       `  "oLanguage": {
              
              "sLengthMenu":    "Locações por Página: _MENU_",
              "sInfo":          "_TOTAL_ Locações",
              "sInfoFiltered":  "(Total: _MAX_ Locações)"
            },   `  but dont work yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using server-side processing mode with `"serverSide": true`, where data is sent for current page only. That is why data for all pages is unavailable to jQuery DataTables, only the current page data.

You can change your server-side script to perform the calculations on the server side and send the required data as an additional data parameter which you can access later in a callback via [`ajax.json()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json()) API method.

Comment: Yes, I think so, for that I am using another ajax request inside the datatable in order to get the 'total amount' from db. So worked well. Solved in my way, but this way that I am wanted I still not found nothing to solve. Thanks!